# Logging into a Django server with Cypress.io programmatically (without using UI)

Tags: django, cypress

Must be missing something obvious but I am very much stuck on logins into Django due to its CSRF protection.

I looked [Check out our example recipes using cy.getCookie() to test logging in using HTML web forms](https://docs.cypress.io/examples/examples/recipes.html#HTML-Web-Forms) but that really doesn't help that much if the first thing it recommends is disabling CSRF.

#### What Django wants:

This is what a normal, CSRF-protected, Django login view is expecting in its incoming POST data:

```
csrfmiddlewaretoken=Y5WscShtwZn3e1eCyahdqPURbfHczLyXfyPRsEOWacdUcGNYUn2EK6pWyicTLSXT
username=guest
password=password
next
```

It is not looking for the CSRF in the request headers and it is not setting `x-csrf-token` on the response headers.

[image]

And, with my code, I am never passing in the csrf token which gets Django to return a 403 error.

```
Cypress.Commands.add("login", (username, password) => {
    var login_url = Cypress.env("login_url");

    cy.visit(login_url)

    var hidden_token = cy.get("input[name='csrfmiddlewaretoken']").value;
    console.log(`hidden_token:${hidden_token}:`)

    console.log(`visited:${login_url}`)
    var cookie = cy.getCookie('csrftoken');
    // debugger;

    var csrftoken = cy.getCookie('csrftoken').value;
    console.log(`csrftoken:${csrftoken}:`) 
    console.log(`request.POST`)

    cy.request({
        method: 'POST',
        form: true,
        url: login_url,
        // body: {'username': 'guest', 'password': 'password', 'csrfmiddlewaretoken': cy.getCookie('csrftoken').value}
        body: {'username': 'guest', 'password': 'password', 'csrfmiddlewaretoken': hidden_token}
    })
})
```

#### Cypress's error:

[image]

I suspect that the POST data has something to do with the token being `undefined` via the both the hidden form input or the cookie acquisition approach, as shown by the `console.log` for either.

Now, I've already started looking at https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress-example-recipes/tree/master/examples/logging-in__csrf-tokens and I think I should be able to adjust **strategy #1: parse token from HTML** to pick up `$("input[name='csrfmiddlewaretoken']").value` but I was hoping someone had done this before.

One other idea I have is to conditionally add a request Middleware to Django that would grab the csrftoken from the request headers and inject into the POST form data when it's missing.  Provided I insert it to fire before the CSRF stuff, would that work?

Last, I was planning to exclude the `sessionid` token from getting reset so that I can run multiple tests after logging in just once.

**env:  Django 1.10, cypress 1.4.2, now upgraded to 2.0.0, same issue.**

Comment: Did you find a solution to your question?

Comment: Did my answer solve your problem?

Answer (score 10):

You can get the first CSRF token required for login using a `HEAD` request and looking at the cookies (no need to parse the page).

Also you can have your custom `cy.login()` return the token (asynchronously, so you need to use `.then()`) instead of having to call `cy.getCookie('csrftoken')` again if you need a token afterwards for POST requests and such:

```js
Cypress.Commands.add('login', (username, password) => {

  return cy.request({
    url: '/login/',
    method: 'HEAD' // cookies are in the HTTP headers, so HEAD suffices
  }).then(() => {

    cy.getCookie('sessionid').should('not.exist')
    cy.getCookie('csrftoken').its('value').then((token) => {
      let oldToken = token
      cy.request({
        url: '/login/',
        method: 'POST',
        form: true,
        followRedirect: false, // no need to retrieve the page after login
        body: {
          username: username,
          password: password,
          csrfmiddlewaretoken: token
        }
      }).then(() => {

        cy.getCookie('sessionid').should('exist')
        return cy.getCookie('csrftoken').its('value')

      })
    })
  })

})
```

Note: The token changes after login, therefore two `cy.getCookie('csrftoken')` calls.

Afterwards you can just use it in the following way in your tests (see https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/csrf/ for why the header is needed):

```js
cy.login().then((csrfToken) => {

  cy.request({
    method: 'POST',
    url: '/api/baz/',
    body: { 'foo': 'bar' },
    headers: { 'X-CSRFToken': csrfToken }
  })

})
```

Comment: I found 'HEAD' did not work, but replacing it with 'GET' was fine, and also needs 'let oldToken = token', but very useful, thanks

Comment: @DohaSimon The cases I can think of where `HEAD` would not work is when there is a proxy server in-between which does not support this method or when  `/login/` leads to a redirection (could be from HTTP to HTTPS). You could have a look using Wireshark. Thanks for the forgotten `let`.

Answer (score 3):

Cypress automatically sends the cookie named "csrftoken" with the request, but Django expects the csrf token to be called "csrfmiddlewaretoken".  Therefore, I had to get the token and pass it by hand as follows:

```
    cy.getCookie('csrftoken')
    .then((csrftoken) => {
        cy.request({
            method: 'POST',
            url: your_url_here,
            // "form: true" is required here for the submitted information to be accessible via request.POST in Django (even though the docs make it sound like a bare 'POST' request can be made without the "form: true")
            form: true,
            body: {
                csrfmiddlewaretoken: csrftoken.value,
                testing: true,
                obj_model: 'Customer',
                field_name: 'name',
                field_value: 'Customer - Testing'
            }
        })
        .then((result) => {
            expect(result.body.success).to.equal(true)
        })
        .then(() => {
            //additional processing here if needed
        })
    })
```

Answer (score 2):

To use Cypress to login programmatically with Django (i.e., without using the UI), the simplest solution is to change two words in the CSRF testing recipe that Cypress provides.

The two changes that I made in the below compared to the Cypress recipe at https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress-example-recipes/blob/master/examples/logging-in__csrf-tokens/cypress/integration/logging-in-csrf-tokens-spec.js are:

1. Changing `_csrf` to `csrfmiddlewaretoken`; and
2. Changing `$html.find("input[name=_csrf]").val()` to `$html.find("input[name=csrfmiddlewaretoken]").val()`

Recipe updated for Django 2.2:

```
// This recipe expands on the previous 'Logging in' examples
// and shows you how to use cy.request when your backend
// validates POSTs against a CSRF token
//
describe('Logging In - CSRF Tokens', function(){
  const username = 'cypress'
  const password = 'password123'

  Cypress.Commands.add('loginByCSRF', (csrfToken) => {
    cy.request({
        method: 'POST',
        url: '/login',
        failOnStatusCode: false, // dont fail so we can make assertions
        form: true, // we are submitting a regular form body
        body: {
          username,
          password,
          csrfmiddlewaretoken: csrfToken // insert this as part of form body
        }
      })
  })

  it('strategy #1: parse token from HTML', function(){
    cy.request('/login')
      .its('body')
      .then((body) => {
        const $html = Cypress.$(body)
        const csrf  = $html.find("input[name=csrfmiddlewaretoken]").val()

        cy.loginByCSRF(csrf)
          .then((resp) => {
            expect(resp.status).to.eq(200)
          })
      })
  })
```

Answer (score 2):

According to the documentation

> In addition, for HTTPS requests, strict referer checking is done by CsrfViewMiddleware. This means that even if a subdomain can set or modify cookies on your domain, it can’t force a user to post to your application since that request won’t come from your own exact domain.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/csrf/#how-it-works

Thus, if you're testing a site using HTTPS request, you might have to explicitly set your `Referer` header.

This solved it for me:

```
cy.request({ url: '/accounts/login/', method: 'HEAD' });
cy.getCookie('csrftoken').then(v => {
  cy.request({
    method: 'POST',
    form: true,
    url: '/accounts/login/',
    headers: {
      Referer: `${Cypress.config('baseUrl')}/accounts/login/`
    },
    body: {
      csrfmiddlewaretoken: v.value,
      login: Cypress.env('agentUsername'),
      password: Cypress.env('agentPassword')
    }
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You are correct, Cypress is not sending the token in the body because it is `undefined`, because of the way you are using `.get()` on the `input` to get the token.

You are using `.get()` as a *synchronous* call, but it's actually **async**. This is because Cypress will intelligently retry finding the DOM element, and that takes an indeterminate amount of time. This is a core concept of Cypress that enables built-in tests. The Cypress documentation details this better than I can, so check that out here: https://docs.cypress.io/guides/core-concepts/introduction-to-cypress.html#Default-Assertions

How you access a property on an element in the DOM should be put in a callback, in your case:

```
cy.get("input[name='csrfmiddlewaretoken']").then($input=>{
    const hidden_token = $input.val()
    cy.request({
        method: 'POST',
        form: true,
        url: login_url,
        // body: {'username': 'guest', 'password': 'password', 'csrfmiddlewaretoken': cy.getCookie('csrftoken').value}
        body: {'username': 'guest', 'password': 'password', 'csrfmiddlewaretoken': hidden_token}
    })
})
```

...

**Pro-tip: using Cypress's doc search will usually lend you what you need**
[image]