# Signin request failing due to invalid csrf

Tags: cypress

I am testing a signin page for keystonejs (http://demo.keystonejs.com/) and cannot get the request to succeed with cypress. A signin request without cypress has the following request headers:

[image]

while a request with a cypress test has the following request headers:

[image]

The only difference I can see is that the cookie is not set in the cypress test request. And because of that the request gets a 403. I am actually using a local version of that server in which I have the email/password configured as the one in the images. The demo site uses a different set provided in that page.

The test is simply:

```
describe('The Keystone Admin UI Signin Page', function () {
  before(function() {
        cy.visit('http://localhost:3000/keystone/signin')
    })

    it('should signin successfully with valid email/password', function () {
        cy.get('#signin-view input[name=email]').clear().type('user@test.e2e');
        cy.get('#signin-view input[name=password]').clear().type('test');
        cy.get('#signin-view button[type=submit]').click();
        cy.get('#react-root').should('be.visible');
    })
})
```

Anyway to get around this?

Comment: I just posted an answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48954728/5548239) that might be useful to you.

Comment: Personally that feels a bit hacky to do. Perhaps some sort of configuration can be introduced to properly deal with csrf.

Comment: btw, we have a full e2e suite based on nightwatch and didn't have to mess around with csrf. It just handled it.

Answer (score 16):

I know this is an older question but I'll post this in case it helps anyone.

The key to fixing this issue for me was that Cypress clears all cookies before each test (https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/clearcookies.html#).

So in the example above (and in my experience):

- The first test (loading the page) is run and passes fine - at this point the browser has set the `csrftoken` cookie
- The second test (submitting the form) runs but before this happens Cypress has deleted the `csrftoken` cookie - hence the error

To fix this I had to whitelist the `csrftoken` cookie in Cypress config which means that it will be exempt from this clearing process:

```
Cypress.Cookies.defaults({
    whitelist: "csrftoken"
})
```

You can do this inline in your test file but the docs recommend using a `support` file:

> A great place to put this configuration is in your cypress/support/index.js file, since it is loaded before any test files are evaluated.

Hope this helps, Stephen.

Comment: This worked perfectly for a Ruby on Rails application. I was having this problem for days. All I had to do is whitelist the session cookie. Thanks a lot!

Comment: The option has now been renamed to `preserve`

Comment: Thanks a lot. I had the same problem with the paypal login during a cypress test. This might fix it

Answer (score 4):

Following on from FlatSteve's answer, using with Laravel and updated prop names use;

```js
Cypress.Cookies.defaults({
    preserve: ["XSRF-TOKEN", "your_laravel_session_name", "remember_token"]
});
```

Comment: Thank you for posting this Laravel specific answer, just got me rolling in my cypress tests!

Comment: do you know how to clear this out after each test? If I close and open a test the same user is logged in

Comment: This should be the newly accepted answer. That's how the cookies seem to be called now

Comment: Headsup:
Cypress.Cookies.defaults() are deprecated in Cypress 9.7.0. 
In a future release, support for Cypress.Cookies.preserveOnce() and Cypress.Cookies.defaults() will be removed.